# Changing Azure web role SDK version

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I'm creating an Azure web role "manually".  (I.e. using cspack.exe and deploying with Powershell rather than using Visual Studio.)

My Web Role SDK version shows as 2.2.6492.2 but I would like to upgrade it to 2.4.  I have tried changing the schemaVersion in the .cscfg file to 2014-06.2.4 but this didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was using cspack.exe v2.2 - upgrading to v2.4 upgraded the SDK in the role.